# OIDC Library issue during the server startup

Tags: java, openid-connect, java-11, tomcat8, pac4j

```
           <pac4j.version>5.6.0</pac4j.version>
                <dependency>
        <groupId>org.pac4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>pac4j-oidc</artifactId>
        <version>${pac4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.pac4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>jee-pac4j</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.pac4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>pac4j-javaee</artifactId>
        <version>${pac4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.pac4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>pac4j-http</artifactId>
        <version>${pac4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.pac4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>pac4j-jwt</artifactId>
        <version>${pac4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.pac4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>pac4j-core</artifactId>
        <version>${pac4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

Application startup failed.java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError org/pac4j/context/JEEContext this error should not thrown as i have already added core libray.

Answer (score 0):

1. Check the `-classpath` variable when the app starts, make sure `pac4j-core` jar file is there
2. Search init log for `ExceptionInInitializerError`, it might lead to `NoClassDefFoundError`

Answer (score 0):

It's a matter of consistency between the versions of the pac4j libraries and the version of the jee-pac4j implementation.

As you can see on the README: https://github.com/pac4j/jee-pac4j, you should use the version 6.0.0 of jee-pac4j with pac4j v5.x.

See the demo as well: https://github.com/pac4j/jee-pac4j-demo/blob/6.0.x/pom.xml#L23

Comment: org.apache.webbeans.exception.WebBeansDeploymentException: javax.enterprise.inject.UnsatisfiedResolutionException: Api type [javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest] is not found with the qualifiers 
Qualifiers: [@javax.enterprise.inject.Default()]
for injection into Method Injection Point, method name :  getWebContext, Bean Owner : [JEEContext, WebBeansType:PRODUCERMETHOD, Name:null, API Types:[java.lang.Object,org.pac4j.core.context.WebContext,org.pac4j.core.context.JEEContext], Qn using above mention version ut getting failed

Comment: java.lang.IllegalStateException: It's not allowed to call getReference(Bean, Type, CreationalContext) before AfterDeploymentValidation
also giving this error

Comment: <classpathDependencyExclude>org.pac4j:javaee-pac4j</classpathDependencyExclude> this solve my problem